# i got an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cartItems.map is not a function. The above error occurred in the <CartScreen> component:

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

i am following a mern stack tutorial of creating a full stack web application using react and i got an error in cartItems.map--  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cartItems.map is not a function. The above error occurred in the  component: , i guess it's because of an array and i have tried to make it an array but it was also not working for me

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartActions';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';

export default function CartScreen(props) {
    const params = useParams();
    const productId = params.id;
    const {search} =useLocation();
    const qtyInUrl = new URLSearchParams(search).get('qty');
    const qty = qtyInUrl?Number(qtyInUrl):1;
  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);
  const  {cartItems } = cart;
  const{ error} = cart;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty));
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId, qty]);

  const removeFromCartHandler = () => {
    // delete action
    // dispatch(removeFromCart(id));
  };
  const navigate=useNavigate()
  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    navigate('/signin?redirect=shipping');
  };
   return (<div className="row top">
      <div className="col-2">
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        {error && <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>}
        {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
          <MessageBox>
            Cart is empty. <Link to="/">Go Shopping</Link>
          </MessageBox>
        ) : (
          <ul>
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.product}>
                <div className="row">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={item.image}
                      alt={item.name}
                      className="small"
                    ></img>
                  </div>
                  <div className="min-30">
                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <select
                      value={item.qty}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(
                          addToCart(item.product, Number(e.target.value))
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div>${item.price}</div>
                  <div>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="col-1">
        <div className="card card-body">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h2>
                Subtotal ({cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty, 0)} items) : $
                {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.qty, 0)}
              </h2>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={checkoutHandler}
                className="primary block"
                disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
              >
                Proceed to Checkout
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: 2 questions. What does your redux store look like and what are the initial values? Does it error out on the first render?

Comment: And can you check cartItems  type ? it's probably not an array

Comment: No there is no error in my redux store @RahulPadalkar

Comment: thanks bro it helped @DanM.CISSOKHO

Comment: thanks bro @DanM.CISSOKHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because your data is not an array. The .map() function only works with arrays. First, you'll need to confirm your data type. Second, you'll need to transform your data into an array.

You should check your cartItems type and change your state to be sure to have an array.

source : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me